# Replace part of string with new value for each time it appears in string, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, include

I want to replace `":player:"` from my string with a player-name from localStorage. And if there are multiple `":player:"` in the string do I want to replace `":player:"` with a different name for each time it comes up in the string so for example.

Lets say that I have a string that looks something like this:

```js
str = ":player: drink 5 sips if :player: has 5 fingers"
```

Then I want the output to be able to be.

```js
str = "Alex drink 5 sips if Harry has 5 fingers"
```

My localStorage data looks like this:
`namesArray = [["Alex",0],["Harry",1]]`

I have tried different variants of str.replace() but it's not working the way that I want it to...

Does it exist something like this?

```js
forEach(str.includes(":player:") => {
  str.replace(":player:", localStorageName[randomNumber].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `replaceAll()` method with a function as the replacement. It can then retrieve from `localStorage` and increment the index each time it's called.

```
localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(['Alex', 'Harry']));
let str = ":player: drink 5 sips if :player: has 5 fingers";
let index = 0;
str = str.replaceAll(':player:', () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))[index++]);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I mean this kind of worked? Did I do it wrong? 
I got responses like 
```str = "Alex drink 5 sips if Alex has 5 fingers"```
when I wanted 
```str = "Alex drink 5 sips if Harry has 5 fingers"```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked. I suspect you didn't store the names correctly in `localStorage`. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: That worked great but thats not how I have stored unfortunately. My localStorage data looks like this: ```namesArray = [["Alex",0],["Harry",1]]````. I've added that to the question.

Comment: The code in the question looked like you had separate localStorage entries for each name. I've updated it to use an array.

Comment: Nice! thank you <3